# PHP regex match all lines

Tags: php, regex

I have a file that has multiple lines using tabs, newlines, and whitespaces. In PHP, I'm trying to loop through a file searching for a specific array of keywords.

Here's the array:
`array('test', 'test2', 'test3')`

File contents:

```
@test
    @test3


       @test2
```

The code:

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
foreach ($array as $k) {
    preg_match('/(@'.$k.')$/m', $file, $m);
}
print_r($m);
```

The problem is it successfully matches the last element of `$array` (test3) regardless of any whitespaces before it. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your question? If you match strings, you should resort to strpos

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that `print_r($m)` is outside of the loop. Obviously, you will only print the last match.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is it successfully matches the last element of $array (test3) **regardless of any whitespaces before it.**

Based on your observations, **bolded above**, I would say you want a match **only** if there's no whitespace before it from the beginning of the line, so let's add a character to say that, the `^`:

```
preg_match('/^(@'.$k.')$/m', $file, $m);
```

and here is a [Rubular to prove it](http://rubular.com/r/nn9vl7PTNJ).

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file_get_contents('file.txt');
$array = array('test', 'test2', 'test3');
$words = implode('|', $array);

if(preg_match_all('/@('.$words.')\s/i', $file, $m))
{
    print_r($m);
}
```

this should match everything you need. but it has a small issue which can be fixed if you add a line break or a space after the last keyword in your file.